# Substring or regex search in Xodus

Tags: xodus

I notice the Xodus entity browser allows searching for property values that begin with a substring. For example:

```
firstName ~ Jo
```

I am wondering whether substring or regex search has been considered. I assume it's not there because it would require iterating over every entity. But even if slow it would be a handy feature in the entity browser, perhaps with a progress bar. Does someone know if this has been considered, or whether a PR adding it would be entertained?

Comment: In my experience Xodus does not have regex but you can have the same effect if you will use and combine operators. I've extensively used Xodus in my project and this was the only option I have used.

Comment: Ok interesting. So do you have a way to combine operators to search for "cat" in the string "dogcatcow"?

Comment: This actually made me dig a code that extensively use Xodus: https://github.com/divroll/backend/blob/cbe4be2853d7b9e9646bf6ff14e121c89c1ccbf5/src/main/java/com/divroll/backend/repository/jee/JeeBaseRespository.java#L92 and see if this is something that was done before. However what you need maybe can't be achieved through operators, but you can definitely be done in Xodus. You can just find using create a transaction and `find` within an Entity type, then from there you can just loop over the result and just do standard Java `contains` this is the only way I can think of doing it on Xodus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search for  "cat" in the string "dogcatcow"

The only possible solution I can think of now is to ceate a transaction and do:

```
EntityIterable entities = txn.find(entityType);
```

From here is it just standard Java iteration and iterate over the properties that contains the keyword "cat"

**Another idea** is to process every property you put into the Xodus store. You can build a typical key value service that will process (e.g. text processing to extract words with Apache Tika) the text properties before or after saving into the store.

So from your example "dogcatcow" you can have 1 key that links with "dog" "cat' and "cow" back to the entity [or the other way around] (so maybe after save is the best time to created this indexed keys).

As a side note, *links* is what sets Xodus apart from other databases in my experience this is very powerful and useful for many cases.

From there is it just simple `findWithLinks` when searching for keys.

You can refer to this code for a sample KV store: 
https://github.com/divroll/backend/blob/master/src/main/java/com/divroll/backend/service/jee/JeeKeyValueService.java

Answer (score 1):

Regex search is not available, but substring search is. There is the `StoreTransaction.findStartingWith(..)` method. Substring search is a kind of property range search for string property values. It is mentioned in the [Searching in Range of Property Values](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#searching-in-range-of-property-values) wiki section.

Here is a [test](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/506147beec1646efebf0c5cfb3958f5e13bf5de6/entity-store/src/test/java/jetbrains/exodus/entitystore/iterate/FindTests.java#L390) which describes the use of `findStartingWith(..)`.

As for performance, substring search doesn't iterate over entities. It uses the same property indices that [search by property value](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#searching-by-property-value) and [property range search](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Entity-Stores#searching-in-range-of-property-values) do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually want to search for a word in the middle of the string value it's not necessarily at the front. I assume it's not there because it would require iterating over every entity. But even if slow it would be a handy feature in the entity browser, perhaps with a progress bar. Does you know if this has been considered, or whether a PR adding it would be entertained?

Comment: Either a  feature request, or a PR - both are welcome in the EntityBrowser repo.

Comment: Cool. Filed a feature request for now, and hopefully I'll be able to do a PR for it too down the road. https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus-entity-browser/issues/23